# PHP | Password validation check before submit

Tags: php, forms

Currently I am coding a function where a user from a website can enter a new password. The form is as follows:

```
<form action="php\change-password.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="newPassword"></input>

    <input type="text" name="confirmNewPassword"></input>

    <button type="submit">verander wachtwoord</button>
</form>
```

The entries in both the input fields shouldn't be empty and they should match.

Is there an easy way to check before submitting the form if the input fields aren't empty and if they match.

I tried doing it with PHP but without any result.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to check, if input aren't empty and has the same value. Try something first. And use `type=password` for passwords, not `text`.

Comment: You can't do something like this with php since it is server-side language,and the server can't really see what someone is doing to the browser.
Maybe you could use ajax call for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this.

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    if($(this).find('input[name="newPassword"]').val() != $(this).find('input[name="confirmNewPassword"]').val()){
        // show error
        return false;
    }
});
```

I would strongly advice to also implement post-submit validation. Jquery validation can easily be worked around.